# Modify the Plugin to use dynamic naming for the form fields added

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the Following Plugin, but every time i create a new fom field, it does not increment the field name, how can i fix this plugin, can't change because we are way ahead with it

```
 /*
Title: Cozeit More plugin by Yasir Atabani
Documentation: na
Author: Yasir O. Atabani
Website: http://www.cozeit.com
Twitter: @yatabani

MIT License, https://github.com/cozeit/czMore/blob/master/LICENSE.md
*/
(function ($, undefined) {
    $.fn.czMore = function (options) {

        //Set defauls for the control
        var defaults = {
            max: 5,
            min: 0,
            onLoad: null,
            onAdd: null,
            onDelete: null,
            styleOverride: false,
        };
        //Update unset options with defaults if needed
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
        $(this).bind("onAdd", function (event, data) {
            options.onAdd.call(event, data);
        });
        $(this).bind("onLoad", function (event, data) {
            options.onLoad.call(event, data);
        });
        $(this).bind("onDelete", function (event, data) {
            options.onDelete.call(event, data);
        });
        //Executing functionality on all selected elements
        return this.each(function () {
            var obj = $(this);
            var i = obj.children(".recordset").length;
            var divPlus = '<div id="btnPlus" class="btnPlus"/>';
            var count = '<input id="' + this.id + '_czMore_txtCount" name="' + this.id + '_czMore_txtCount" type="hidden" value="0" size="5" />';

            obj.before(count);
            var recordset = obj.children("#first");
            obj.after(divPlus);
            var set = recordset.children(".recordset").children().first();
            var btnPlus = obj.siblings("#btnPlus");

            if(!options.styleOverride) {
              btnPlus.css({
                  'float': 'right',
                  'border': '0px',
                  'background-image': 'url("/default/includes/themes/images/add.png")',
                  'background-position': 'center center',
                  'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
                  'height': '25px',
                  'width': '25px',
                  'cursor': 'pointer',
              });
            }

            if (recordset.length) {
                obj.siblings("#btnPlus").click(function () {
                    var i = obj.children(".recordset").length;
                    var item = recordset.clone().html();
                    i++;
                    item = item.replace(/\[([0-9]\d{0})\]/g, "[" + i + "]");
                    item = item.replace(/\_([0-9]\d{0})\_/g, "_" + i + "_");
                    //$(element).html(item);
                    //item = $(item).children().first();
                    //item = $(item).parent();

                    obj.append(item);
                    loadMinus(obj.children().last());
                    minusClick(obj.children().last());
                    if (options.onAdd != null) {
                        obj.trigger("onAdd", i);
                    }

                    obj.siblings("input[name$='czMore_txtCount']").val(i);
                    return false;
                });
                recordset.remove();
                for (var j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                    loadMinus(obj.children()[j]);
                    minusClick(obj.children()[j]);
                    if (options.onAdd != null) {
                        obj.trigger("onAdd", j);
                    }
                }

                if (options.onLoad != null) {
                    obj.trigger("onLoad", i);
                }
                //obj.bind("onAdd", function (event, data) {
                //If you had passed anything in your trigger function, you can grab it using the second parameter in the callback function.
                //});
            }

            function resetNumbering() {
                $(obj).children(".recordset").each(function (index, element) {
                   $(element).find('input:text, input:password, input:file, select, textarea').each(function(){
                        old_name = this.name;
                        new_name = old_name.replace(/\_([0-9]\d{0})\_/g, "_" + (index + 1) + "_");
                        this.id = this.name = new_name;
                        //alert(this.name);
                    });
                    index++
                    minusClick(element);
                });
            }

            function loadMinus(recordset) {
                var divMinus = '<div id="btnMinus" class="btnMinus" />';
                $(recordset).children().first().before(divMinus);
                var btnMinus = $(recordset).children("#btnMinus");
                if(!options.styleOverride) {
                  btnMinus.css({
                      'float': 'right',
                      'border': '0px',
                      'background-image': 'url("/default/includes/themes/images/remove.png")',
                      'background-position': 'center center',
                      'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
                      'height': '25px',
                      'width': '25px',
                      'cursor': 'poitnter',
                  });
              }
            }

            function minusClick(recordset) {
                $(recordset).children("#btnMinus").click(function () {
                    var i = obj.children(".recordset").length;
                    var id = $(recordset).attr("data-id")
                    $(recordset).remove();
                    resetNumbering();
                    obj.siblings("input[name$='czMore_txtCount']").val(obj.children(".recordset").length);
                    i--;
                    if (options.onDelete != null) {
                        if (id != null)
                            obj.trigger("onDelete", id);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

the above is the jquery code we found on the sourceforge website and tried this code, we have been using this function in other instances so trying to modify its behavior, looks like it do support dynamic naming but somehow it is not working

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML code the form fields must have the name in format someText_1_someAnotherText, and then the plugin will increment the number between the 2 underscores.

Example:

`<input type="text" name="name_1_repeat" class="form-control" id="name_1_repeat">`

The resulted code from the add button is

`<input type="text" name="name_1_repeat" class="form-control" id="name_1_repeat">
<input type="text" name="name_2_repeat" class="form-control" id="name_2_repeat">`

And so on..